# Yosemite Storage Analysis

Tags: backup, storage, macos

I have Yosemite on MacBook Air and continuously get en error about storage usage. It keeps saying there isn't enough empty space on disk. About this Mac says that I have 65.96GB of other type files. When I get info about home directory it says 57.69GB is the size of home directory. However when I sum up the sizes of each directory under home, it is only about 12GB of data. I can't find where the remaining 46GB is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found it :)

Under home directory Library has all the data and most of them came from mail app which includes downloaded imap copies and attachments. I erased them by using mail app and everything is fine for now.

Comment: Please add the whole Path to the Library folder, and explain exactly how did you delete the files - from Finder or from Mail itself.